# How to delete a local login account/windows user account? Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, login-screen

I have created a local user account two weeks ago on my win10 machine.
Now I have deleted this user account but it is still offered at startup as an login option,
which makes no sense, cause the account is already deleted.

The account I have created is called "noce", as you can see, it does not appear under users,
but why can I still login using this account?

[image]

**EDIT:**

The funny thing is:
When I hit `Ctrl + Alt + Del` and choose switch user, then the deleted account does not show up.
But it does show up on a fresh machine start!

Comment: Somebody should submit a detailed answer instead of a temporary comment.  All temporary commentary has been flagged.  If you reference an external website you should quote and cite the website[.](https://windowsreport.com/login-screen-shows-deleted-user/)

Comment: Which website was it?